# Chrome Required value 'version' is missing or invalid. It must be between 1-4 dot-separated integers each between 0 and 65536

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I have been trying to create a personalized theme, but every time I upload chrome says **"required value 'version' is missing or invalid. It must be between 1-4 dot-separated integers each between 0 and 65536.'** This is the first time I've tried this so I don't know what it is I have to change. Even if I did, what would I change it too. How can I fix this?

```
﻿{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Chrome Themes",
  "theme": {
    "images" : {
      "theme_frame" : "Images/Cracked Dimensions.jpg",
      "theme_toolbar" : "Images/Cracked Dimensions.jpg",
      "theme_ntp_background" : "Images/Halloween Whopper.jpg",
    "theme_tab_background" : "Images/Halloween Whopper.jpg"}
    }
    ,"colors" : {
        "ntp_link": [118,17,25], 
    "ntp_text": [118,17,25], 
    "ntp_section_link": [118,17,25], 
    "ntp_section_text": [51 , 55 , 58],
    "ntp_background": [51 , 55 , 58], 
    "frame": [51 , 55 , 58], 
    "toolbar": [51 , 55 , 58], 
    "tab_text": [118,17,25], 
    "tab_background_text": [51 , 55 , 58], 
    "bookmark_text": [118,17,25]
    },
    "tints" : {
                "buttons" : [0.33, 0.5, 0.47],
                "frame_inactive": [0.50, 0.50, 0.50], 
                "frame_incognito_inactive": [0.50, 0.50, 0.50] 
    },
    "properties" : {
        "ntp_background_alignment" : "center",
    "ntp_background_repeat": "no-repeat"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

This is the correct way to define "version" and "manifest_version"

```
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
```

Comment: I realized that `"version": "v0.0.1"` is invalid, it should not contain letters such as "v" so: `"version": "0.0.1"`

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same issue and i finally found the solution that worked for me.
You need to wrap the version number in double quotes as well.

```
"version": "1.0",
```

Hope this would help!!

Answer (score 3):

As the error noted, you must have a `version` key, with one to four numerical values delimited by a `.`.

E.g.:

```
"version": "45.0.2454.93"
```

The full JSON:

```
{
  "version": "45.0.2454.93",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Chrome Themes",
  "theme": {
    "images" : {
      "theme_frame" : "Images/Cracked Dimensions.jpg",
      "theme_toolbar" : "Images/Cracked Dimensions.jpg",
      "theme_ntp_background" : "Images/Halloween Whopper.jpg",
    "theme_tab_background" : "Images/Halloween Whopper.jpg"}
    }
    ,"colors" : {
        "ntp_link": [118,17,25], 
    "ntp_text": [118,17,25], 
    "ntp_section_link": [118,17,25], 
    "ntp_section_text": [51 , 55 , 58],
    "ntp_background": [51 , 55 , 58], 
    "frame": [51 , 55 , 58], 
    "toolbar": [51 , 55 , 58], 
    "tab_text": [118,17,25], 
    "tab_background_text": [51 , 55 , 58], 
    "bookmark_text": [118,17,25]
    },
    "tints" : {
                "buttons" : [0.33, 0.5, 0.47],
                "frame_inactive": [0.50, 0.50, 0.50], 
                "frame_incognito_inactive": [0.50, 0.50, 0.50] 
    },
    "properties" : {
        "ntp_background_alignment" : "center",
    "ntp_background_repeat": "no-repeat"
    }
  }
```

Comment: chrome now says **"Manifest is not valid JSON. Line: 3, column: 3, Syntax error."** Why doesn't chrome recognize it? @Mureinik

Comment: @YnezTorres I missing a comma after the `version` entry, sorry. Edited and fixed.

Comment: Chrome now says **Could not load 'C:\Users\Titan\Downloads\Chrome Themes\Images\Images/Cracked Dimensions.jpg",** @Mureinik Is the file too large or the picture have the wrong dimensions? What are the requirements for theme frame and toolbar? Thanks for trying to help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
```

use this code.you will get solutions.